# How to display TileWMS layer 0-360 degrees

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

i receive from geoserver TileWMS layer that have extent from 0 to 360 degrees, and when i load this layer on map i can see only part of layer, becose my map have extent from -180 to 180 degrees. How i can reprojecting this layer?

source layer on geoserver
[image: source layer on geoserver]

when i load layer on map
[image: when i load layer on map]

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a custom tile url function to change the default tileWMS bbox which uses -180 to +180 to positive only values

```
var defaultUrlFunction = source.getTileUrlFunction().bind(source);

source.setTileUrlFunction(function(tileCoord, ratio, projection) {
    var tileExtent = source.getTileGrid().getTileCoordExtent(tileCoord);
    var defaultBbox = '&BBOX=' + [tileExtent[1],tileExtent[0],tileExtent[3],tileExtent[2]].join('%2C');
    if (tileExtent[0] < 0) {
        tileExtent[0] += 360;
        tileExtent[2] += 360;
    }
    var newBbox = '&BBOX=' + [tileExtent[1],tileExtent[0],tileExtent[3],tileExtent[2]].join('%2C');
    return defaultUrlFunction(tileCoord, ratio, projection).replace(defaultBbox, newBbox);
});
```

Note that `source.getTileGrid()` will only retrieve a TileWMS tile grid specified in the source constructor, for example

`tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({ extent: ol.proj.get('EPSG:4326').getExtent() })`

and not one created by default.